# Trying to get random value in specified range?

Tags: java, random

for one of my assignments I am trying to generate a random number between 16-26 (both inclusive). I've read around and tried different methods but for some reason it goes over the specified range. This is what I have at the moment:

```
int dealerHand = 16 + (int) (Math.random() * ((26 - 16) + 16));
```

Any idea on why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: This must have been asked a million times ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((26 - 16) + 16)` is the same as `(26 + (-16 + 16)` so `26 + 0`, so now the problem should be more evident:

```
int dealerHand = 16 + (int) (Math.random() * 26);
```

which returns a number between `16` and `42`.

What you need to do is closer to this:

```
int dealerHand = 16 + (int) (Math.random() * (26 - 16));
```

But watch out for the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) of `Math.random()`: the returned number is `>= 0.0` and `< 1.0`. Which means this code would generate numbers in the range `[16;26)` (that is, 26 is not included). As you want to include it this is the real formula:

```
int dealerHand = 16 + (int) (Math.random() * (26 - 16 + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks, was updating the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int dealerHand = 16 + r.nextInt(11);
```